# SCREEN A -> press button > 10s operation -> it's need to show SCREEN B (I use a Storyboard)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uistoryboard

I create a UI using a `storyboard`, and on one of my screens I start to perform a heavy time consuming operation (the waiting dialog is being shown in this time), and after finishing this operation I need to show another screen with getting results.

What should I use for this case:

1. Declare a new screen in the `Storyboard` and use `SEGUE`
2. Create a `nib`-file dynamically
3. Other?

**EDIT:**

Question is - how can I move from one screen to another after performing time consuming operation (I use a Storyboard). It seems that if I use nibs - I should only change rootViewControoler

**SCREEN A -> press button > 10s operation -> it's need to show SCREEN B (I use a Storyboard).
How can I do it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of things that you could could do in this situation.

It sounds like you want to present a waiting view modally.  A commonly used 3rd party class for this is [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) which allows you to present a heads-up display modally in your view during the execution of a long-running task.

With `MBProgressHUD` you present an instance of the HUD in your view and remove it after the task completes.  It requires no nib loading, etc.

Just one option.  It depends on what you want to present to the user.

EDIT:  It appears the OP is mostly interested in how to transition to a new view controller following a lengthy operation under Storyboards.  I think the solution is `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`.  So, set up the segue of interest in the Storyboard and call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` on the view controller in whose context the long-running task is being performed.

Comment: it seems you didn't catch my question, it's my fault,sorry. Question is - how can I move from one screen to another after performing time consuming operation (I use a Storyboard). It seems that if I use nibs - I should only change rootViewControoler

Comment: Sorry - I edited.  I think you just want `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` unless I'm still misunderstanding the question.